# how to check view state exists in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

i just implement one editable grid view with asp.net 4.0. now i just set ViewState for storing only for this document with this code :

```
 protected void DDL_Types1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender as DropDownList;
        GridViewRow row = ddl.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        if (!ddl.SelectedItem.Value.Equals("-1"))
        {
            ViewState["type_id"] = ddl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    protected void DDL_StateNames1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender as DropDownList;
        GridViewRow row = ddl.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        if (!ddl.SelectedItem.Value.Equals("-1"))
        {
            ViewState["state_id"] = ddl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    protected void chk_UserOFC1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender as CheckBox;
        GridViewRow row = chk.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        ViewState["UserOFC"] = chk.Checked.ToString();
    }
    protected void chk_UserVAT1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender as CheckBox;
        GridViewRow row = chk.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        ViewState["UserVAT"] = chk.Checked.ToString();
    }
    protected void chk_UserINV1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender as CheckBox;
        GridViewRow row = chk.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        ViewState["UserINV"] = chk.Checked.ToString();
    }
    protected void chk_UserNone1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender as CheckBox;
        GridViewRow row = chk.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        ViewState["UserNone"] = chk.Checked.ToString();
    }
```

now at grid view row updating i have to check that ViewState exists or not because when user doesn't select it or check it check box values then it not accessed.

here is my grid view row updating code :

```
protected void  GV_ViewCustomers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GV_ViewCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int customerid = Convert.ToInt32(GV_ViewCustomers.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Name"].ToString()) && !ViewState["type_id"].Equals("-1"))
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                string owname = null, ownmono = null, room = null, build = null, road = null, area = null, city = null, mobile = null, phone = null, email = null, cpname = null, cpmono = null, remark = null;
                bool? UserOFC = null, UserVAT = null, UserINV = null, UserNone = null;
                int? country_id = null, state_id = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Ownername"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    owname = e.NewValues["Ownername"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Ownermob"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    ownmono = e.NewValues["Ownermob"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["ContactPerson"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    cpname = e.NewValues["ContactPerson"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["ContactPersonmob"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    cpmono = e.NewValues["ContactPersonmob"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Phone"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    phone = e.NewValues["Phone"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Mobile"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    mobile = e.NewValues["Mobile"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Room"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    room = e.NewValues["Room"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Build"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    build = e.NewValues["Build"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Road"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    road = e.NewValues["Road"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Area"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    area = e.NewValues["Area"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["City"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    city = e.NewValues["City"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!ViewState["country_id"].Equals("-1"))
                {
                    country_id = int.Parse(ViewState["country_id"].ToString());
                }
                if (!ViewState["state_id"].Equals("-1"))
                {
                    state_id = int.Parse(ViewState["state_id"].ToString());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Email"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    email = e.NewValues["Email"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues["Remark"].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    remark = e.NewValues["Remark"].ToString().Trim();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewState["UserOFC"].ToString()))
                   //error occurs doesn't selected from user
                {
                    UserOFC = bool.Parse(ViewState["UserOFC"].ToString());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewState["UserVAT"].ToString()))
                {
                    UserVAT = bool.Parse(ViewState["UserVAT"].ToString());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewState["UserINV"].ToString()))
                {
                    UserINV = bool.Parse(ViewState["UserINV"].ToString());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewState["UserNone"].ToString()))
                {
                    UserNone = bool.Parse(ViewState["UserNone"].ToString());
                }
                db.UpdateParty(e.NewValues["Name"].ToString().Trim(), int.Parse(ViewState["type_id"].ToString()), owname, ownmono, room, build, road, area, city, phone, mobile, email, cpname, cpmono, UserOFC, UserVAT, UserINV, UserNone, state_id, country_id, remark, db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Ref_no).FirstOrDefault(), customerid);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                GV_ViewCustomers.EditIndex = -1;
                this.FillGrid((String)Session["StartAlpha"] ?? null, (int)Session["GroupByENTYPE"], (String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchText"] ?? null);
                UpdatePanel10.Update();
                MPE.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) collection implements a key/value [StateBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Web.UI.StateBag%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You have two out-of-the-box options to check if a key exists.

#### Simple null check

```
if (ViewState["type_id"] != null && !ViewState["type_id"].Equals("-1")) 
{

}
```

#### Use the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298519%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

```
if (ViewState.Contains("type_id") && !ViewState["type_id"].Equals("-1")) 
{

}
```